# Use Chart.js in Jupyter Notebook throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined`

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, chart.js, jupyter

I'm trying to use Chart.js in Jupyter Notebook (to solve this [issue](https://github.com/mljar/bloxs/issues/1)), but the chart is not showing up in Jupyter Notebook (but it is working in Google Colab).

I've created a minimal reproducible example in a similar way as in: [Python Jupyter Notebook: Embed an interactive plot in the _repr_html_() method of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660677/python-jupyter-notebook-embed-an-interactive-plot-in-the-repr-html-method-o) - cell is returning HTML representation with chart

However, the example code is not working in Jupyter Notebook:

```py
class ClassTwo:
    def _repr_html_(self):
        
        ret = """
        <h2>Chart</h2>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
            
        <canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:700px"></canvas>
        
        <script>
          var xyValues = [{x:50, y:7}, {x:60, y:8}, {x:70, y:8}, {x:80, y:9}, {x:90, y:9},];

          new Chart("myChart", {
            type: "scatter",
            data: {
              datasets: [{
                pointRadius: 4,
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
                data: xyValues
              }]
            },
            options: {
              legend: {display: false},
              scales: {
                xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 40, max:100}}],
                yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:10}}],
              }
            }
          });
        </script>
        """
        return ret
    

ClassTwo()
```

The expected output should be a chart. Instead, I got an error in the developer console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
    at <anonymous>:4:11
```

#### Screenshot from local Jupyter Notebook

[image]

#### Google Colab

The above code snippet is working in Google Colab. I have no idea why it is working in Colab and not working in the local Jupyter Notebook?

Any ideas why `Chart` is not defined?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to solve it. There was a problem because `chartjs` was not loaded on time. I fixed this with `requirejs` - the package is loaded with `require`. Here is my working code:

```py
class ClassTwo:
    def _repr_html_(self):
        
        ret = """
        
<canvas name="chart" id="f53605da-a239-4014-873c-7c0f5282ff55" width="538" height="538"></canvas>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        paths: {
            chartjs: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min'
        }
    });

    require(['chartjs'], function(Chart) {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('f53605da-a239-4014-873c-7c0f5282ff55').getContext('2d');
        
        var xyValues = [{x:50, y:7}, {x:60, y:8}, {x:70, y:8}, {x:80, y:9}, {x:90, y:9},];

          new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "scatter",
            data: {
              datasets: [{
                pointRadius: 4,
                pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
                data: xyValues
              }]
            },
            options: {
              legend: {display: false},
              scales: {
                xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 40, max:100}}],
                yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:10}}],
              }
            }
          });
        
        
    });
</script>
        """
        return ret
    

ClassTwo()
```